# How to detect shadow under /below a segmented region?

Tags: matlab, shadow, pixel, image-segmentation

I am working on a project (named :Shadow based renal stone detection ) in which after applying region growing to detect stone (as most brighter part in the image)
I have to verify the shadow under the stone with gray values( of shadow )ranging between 10 to 40 .
How may I complete my task ?
 Screenshot along with this question may provide more clarity to my question.[image: screenshot]

Any assistance regarding this matter will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**This  is is the original image:[image: original image]

and this is the cropped image of kidney with contrast enhancement and Gaussian filter applied over it [image: filtered Image]

Comment: Doctors say : in an ultrasound image of kidney containing stone , mostly stone is the the brightest area in that image and to verify that brighter area to be an actual stone a shadow is always there below the stone because the stone stops light rays to pass through.

Comment: you have no "light rays" in ultra**sound** image. you probably mean the stone absorb the sound waves.

Comment: (1) please attach the original image. (2) do you now the direction of the sound waves, that is, the direction in the image that defines "under/below"?

Comment: I have attached  the images.

Comment: (2) As we can see in the original picture ,the direction of waves is upside of kidney travelling towards downside . @Shai